# Load data in chart series from another thread in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, charts, concurrency

JavaFX uses observable lists for their chart series. I want to load the data in the series from a different thread, and I have done so by using Task and Platform.runLater. However, the UI is still not very responsive and the data does not look smooth coming in.

I would like the following to happen:

- The UI to remain responsive.
- The data loads in the graph smoothly - one at a time in each series.

  Order of operations:

  1. Load the page
  2. Load the empty chart series in the graph
  3. Press the generate button
  4. Load data into each series

Relevant part of the code:

Loads series into chart

```
private static ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> pathSeries = FXCollections.observableArrayList();     

final LineChart<Number,Number> pathChart = 
            new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

    for (int n=0; n<proc.getNumPath(); n++)
    {
        pathSeries.add(new Series<Number, Number>());
    }

    pathChart.getData().addAll(pathSeries);
```

Loads data to series

```
    Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void call() {

        // PATH SERIES
        for (int n=0; n<proc.getNumPath(); n++)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<=proc.getM(); i++)
            {   
                int pathNumber = n;
                int dataIndex = i;

                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pathSeries.get(pathNumber).getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(proc.getT()[dataIndex], 
                                proc.getX()[pathNumber][dataIndex]));
                    }
                });
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    updateMessage("Cancelled");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};

@FXML
public void initialize(){

    generateButton.setOnAction(e -> {
        pathWorker = new Thread(task);
        pathWorker.setDaemon(true);
        pathWorker.start();
    });
}
```

How can I improve my code without getting too complicated?

[image]

Comment: You're probably not going to like this comment, but that looks like a huge amount of data. The chart API, imho, is not really designed for data on that scale and you might find you need to roll your own implementation (e..g using a canvas) to get a responsive UI with that much data. The basic problem is that each data point is represented by a node in the scene graph, and each of those nodes has a large number of properties and its appearance is controller by fairly expensive CSS code. You can try a couple of things - e.g. turn off animation on the chart - but this just might be too much data.

Comment: I think calling Thread.sleep(100); would help with GUI response. Play with the numbers. You data will take longer to load though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside the for loop.

```
Thread.sleep(100);
```